# looking for datepicker for birthday not jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, datepicker

am looking for a js/jQuery plugins datepicker like this http://www.styledisplay.com/mootoolsdatepicker/ because this one uses MooTools, with dropdown year and month

thanks a lot

Comment: Why not the jQuery UI datepicker?

Comment: @pete just ressource issue i have big php application don't want to use jQuery UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery UI has a built in datepicker. You can build/tailor your distribution of jQuery UI to your needs if your concern is that it is resource intensive.

Try building it with only the necessary modules and you should be fine.

jQuery UI is very stable/customizable and should more than suit your needs.

Comment: Did you even look at the available options? http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Answer (score 1):

I have used

- Kevin Lucks Date Picker multiple times:
  http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/

but there are many more options:

- http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-jquery-calendar-and-date-picker-plugins-for-web-designers/

But I would really really advise you to use jQuery UI Datepicker it is the most stable and supported datepicker and when it comes to ressource concerns, use the google cdn api and load it from there so you don't need to add more .js files to your project.